# Request method 'GET' not supported] error for method using @DeleteMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, get, http-delete

I'm getting a error like:

> Request method 'GET' not supported for a method (deleteProductById)

using the `@DeleteMapping` annotation whenever I visit the URL mapped to said method (http://localhost:8083/deleteproductbyid/1). The app works when I change the annotation for the method to @GetMapping but that causes other issues.

Here's the relevant code:

```
package com.democrudexample.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.democrudexample.model.Product;
import com.democrudexample.services.CrudService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class CrudRestController {

    @Autowired
    private CrudService service;
    
    @GetMapping("/getproductlist")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    public List<Product> fetchProductList() {
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
        //logic to fetch list from database
        products = service.fetchProductList();
        return products;
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/addproduct")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    public Product saveProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        return service.saveProductToDB(product);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/getproductbyid/{id}")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    public Product fetchProductById(@PathVariable int id) {
        return service.fetchProductById(id).get();
        
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping(value = "/deleteproductbyid/{id}")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    public String deleteProductById(@PathVariable int id) {
        return service.deleteProductById(id);
    }
}
```

```
package com.democrudexample.services;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.democrudexample.model.Product;
import com.democrudexample.repository.CrudRepo;

@Service
public class CrudService {

    @Autowired
    private CrudRepo repo;
    
    public List<Product> fetchProductList(){
        return repo.findAll();
    }
    
    public Product saveProductToDB(Product product) {
        return repo.save(product);
    }
    
    public Optional<Product> fetchProductById(int id) {
        
        return repo.findById(id);
    }
    
    public String deleteProductById(int id) {
        String result;
        try {
            repo.deleteById(id);
            result = "Product sucessfully deleted";
            System.out.println(result);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            result = "Product id is not valid";
            System.out.println(result);
        }
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I commented out the result and everything related to it in the deleteProductById method and it seems to be working just fine now. After having looked at the console, the error seems to have been some issues with parsing the text.

Comment: When you say you "visit" the mapped URL do you mean you go to that address in a browser? That will result in a GET, not a DELETE

Comment: @darrengorman Yes, so I changed the mapping to a GET method so it'll display in the browser without any issues. Will that cause any issues? It seems to be deleting the data from the DB without any issues.

Comment: @GottaCodeEmAll If the method is supposed to delete stuffs, it should be DELETE method. Not a GET method.

Comment: @AbhinabaChakraborty Got it. I changed it back to a DELETE method and commented out the result and returned null in the deleteProductById method and it seems to be working fine now.

Comment: btw you can add `@CrossOrigin` annotiation on the class name instead of every method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By annotating the method as @DeleteMapping, you are making this a HTTP DELETE operation. Refer this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) for more details about different HTTP requests.

However, when you access an URL in browser, browser always sends a GET request, whereas your Resource is expecting a DELETE request. Hence you are getting the error.

You can use tools like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) or you can write a small code in Javascript to send a DELETE request to the server.